# Can't serve node_modules as static on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have hosted my node app on a AWS Linux machine.My code is working perfectly on openshift, its serve node_modules as static to access my angular.But in AWS host its doesn't.

```
var app = express();
app.use('/bower_components/', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ipaddress'), function() {
// server.maxConnections = 2;
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: What error are you seeing? Did you install packages on aws or not?

Comment: I have access to log on  my instance.without packages server will not start no? All discrepancies are installed and  node server start perfectly.Only the issue is serving static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long Re-search I found a solution that I have to forward reqest from nginx to nodejs , nginx will serve them as it exported by node.

I added my site config on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-site`

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name mysite.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Hope this help some one who having this issue.